# On the reciprocal of $I(n^2) - \frac{2(q - 1)}{q}$, if $q^k n^2$ is a(n) (odd) perfect number with special prime $q$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Denote the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$ by $\sigma(x)=\sigma_1(x)$.  Denote the *abundancy index* of $x$ by $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$.

A number $N$ is said to be *perfect* if $\sigma(N)=2N$.  (Equivalently, $N$ is perfect if $I(N)=2$.)

It is [known](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414424) that if $q^k n^2$ is perfect, where $q$ is an **odd prime** satisfying $\gcd(q,n)=1$, then we obtain
$$i(q) := \dfrac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \dfrac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)} = \dfrac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)} = \dfrac{2s(n^2)}{D(q^k)}, \tag{1}$$
where $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$ is the *deficiency* of $x$ and $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$ is the *aliquot sum* of $x$.

(Note that $i(q)$ is odd.)  We then obtain
$$\sigma(n^2) = q^k \cdot i(q)$$
and
$$n^2 = \dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{2} \cdot i(q),$$
so that
$$\gcd(n^2, \sigma(n^2)) = i(q)\cdot\gcd\Bigg(\dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{2},q^k \Bigg) = i(q). \tag{2}$$

Additionally, we can rewrite Equation **(1)** as
$$i(q) = \dfrac{\sigma(n^2)}{q^k} = \dfrac{D(n^2)}{s(q^k)} = \dfrac{(q - 1)D(n^2)}{q^k - 1} = \dfrac{\sigma(n^2) - (q - 1)D(n^2)}{q^k - (q^k - 1)} = q\sigma(n^2) - 2(q - 1)n^2. \tag{3}$$

---

Let us consider the equation
$$\dfrac{2n^2}{\sigma(q^k)} = q\sigma(n^2) - 2(q - 1)n^2.$$

Dividing through by $qn^2$, we get
$$\dfrac{2}{q\sigma(q^k)} = I(n^2) - \dfrac{2(q - 1)}{q},$$
which implies that the reciprocal of $I(n^2) - \dfrac{2(q - 1)}{q}$ is an integer as
$$\dfrac{q \sigma(q^k)}{2} = \dfrac{1}{I(n^2) - \dfrac{2(q - 1)}{q}}$$
**is** an integer (since $\sigma(q^k) \equiv 2 \pmod 4$).

---

Let us now consider the equation
$$\dfrac{D(m^2)}{s(p^k)} = p\sigma(m^2) - 2(p - 1)m^2,$$
for the case of **odd perfect numbers** $p^k m^2$ with special prime $p$ satisfying $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Dividing through by $pm^2$, we obtain
$$\dfrac{D(m^2)}{pm^2 s(p^k)} = I(m^2) - \dfrac{2(p - 1)}{p}.$$
Taking the reciprocals of both sides, we get
$$\dfrac{pm^2 s(p^k)}{D(m^2)} = \dfrac{1}{I(m^2) - \dfrac{2(p - 1)}{p}}, \tag{4}$$
which **must be an integer** by the considerations in the previous section.

Dividing both sides of Equation **(4)** by $p$, we obtain
$$\dfrac{m^2 s(p^k)}{D(m^2)} = \dfrac{\sigma(p^k)}{2} = \dfrac{1}{p}\cdot\Bigg(\dfrac{1}{I(m^2) - \dfrac{2(p - 1)}{p}}\Bigg),  \tag{5}$$
which **is still an integer**.

Here is my question:

> **Does it follow from Equation **(5)** that the divisibility constraint
> $$D(m^2) \mid m^2$$
> must hold?**

Note that, for odd perfect numbers $p^k m^2$ with special prime $p$ satisfying $\gcd(p,m)=1$, we actually have the lower bound
$$i(p) \geq 3,$$
a result of [Dris (2012)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html).

Lastly, note that for *even perfect numbers* $q n^2$ with *Mersenne prime* $q$, we actually have
$$i(q) = 1.$$

Comment: FYI, one has $\dfrac{m^2}{D(m^2)}=\dfrac{m^2}{2m^2-\frac{2p^km^2}{\sigma(p^k)}}=\dfrac{\sigma(p^k)}{2\sigma(p^k)-2p^k}=\dfrac{p^{k+1}-1}{2p^k-2}$. When $k=1$, this is an integer. This is not an integer when $p=k=5$.

Comment: Indeed, I already know that the biconditional
$$D(m^2) \mid m^2 \iff k = 1$$
holds, @mathlove.  Please see **Lemma 1.3** in [this paper](https://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-23/NNTDM-23-2-012-020.pdf).

Comment: I guess another way to rephrase my question is:  Does the condition
$$\gcd(m^2, s(p^k)) = 1$$
hold?  This equation is equivalent to
$$\gcd(m^2, p^k - 1) = 1.$$
(Note that we **know** that $\gcd(m^2, p^k) = 1$.)

Comment: "I guess another way to rephrase my question is: Does the condition $\gcd(m^2,s(p^k))=1$ hold?" Well, I don't get it. Are you saying that if we can prove that $\gcd(m^2,s(p^k))=1$, then we can say that $D(m^2)\mid m^2$ ? I don't think so. Consider $\dfrac{6\times 35}{15}=14$. I think that if we can prove that $\gcd(D(m^2),s(p^k))=1$, then we can say that $D(m^2)\mid m^2$.

Comment: And I think that I can prove that $\gcd(D(m^2),s(p^k))=\sigma(p^k)-p^k$, so one can say that $\gcd(D(m^2),s(p^k))=1\iff k=1$.

Comment: Well, in your example, $\gcd(6, 35)=1$.

Comment: So my conjecture is that, if one can prove that $\gcd(m^2, s(p^k)) = 1$, then one can show $D(m^2) \mid m^2$.

Comment: Note that, evidently, $\gcd(D(m^2), s(p^k)) = s(p^k)$, as $s(p^k) \mid D(m^2)$ follows from the fact that
$$i(p) = \dfrac{D(m^2)}{s(p^k)}$$
**is** an integer.

Comment: $\gcd(6,35)=1$, but $15$ does not divide $6$. This means that $\gcd(m^2,s(p^k))=1$ does not imply $D(m^2)\mid m^2$.

Comment: Ahh, now I get your point @mathlove.  You are correct.